# Add product to wishlist without reloading page

Tags: ajax, wishlist

How can I add a product to my wishlist without the page reloading? I tried [the answer on this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3083/add-to-wishlist-without-redirect-to-wishlist) but it still reloads the page.

Using

> return false;

and

> event.preventDefault();

stops the link from adding the product to the wishlist altogether on my homepage while it doesn't affect the link in the single product pages (still reloads but adds the product to wishlist).

How do I pull this off? I want a pop-up for logged in customers to confirm that the product is added to wishlist but I don't know how to use AJAX on Magento's wishlist.

Here's my development site: [LINK](http://bedford-webdesign.co.uk/projects/kindskin-mag/)

Comment: please refer this link , this will helpful sortly 
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/59723/add-to-wishlist-without-redirecting-to-wishlist-page

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this would be to create your own controller and action that will take the same information add to the wishlist but simply return a json response with success or a failure message.

In this way you can skip all the redirect stuff and work with a simply ajax action.