# "Add to wishlist" without redirecting to wishlist page

Tags: magento-1.9, redirect, wishlist

When clicking on the `add to wishlist` button, I want to remain on the same page & perform the add function without redirecting to the wishlist page - is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to rewrite the method `_addItemToWishList` from the controller `Mage_Wishlist_IndexController` and replace the last line.
Instead of

```
$this->_redirect('*', array('wishlist_id' => $wishlist->getId()));
```

You have to put:

```
 $this->_redirectReferer();
```

**[EDIT]**.

[Here is an example](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/10842/146) on how you can rewrite a controller.
You need to rewrite (like I said) `Mage_Wishlist_IndexController`. The controller is found in `app/code/core/Mage/Wishlist/controllers/IndexController.php`.

Comment: hi boss, thanks a lot for helping me again , again & again....

please tell me which in which folder and file..?...

Comment: @BabyinMagento2 See my edit.

Comment: ultimate you are ,as always.....

Comment: i will copy app/code/core/Mage/Wishlist/controllers/IndexController.php.

and do changes here : app/code/Local/Mage/Wishlist/controllers/IndexController.php.

Comment: Not working for me...Any Suggestions?

Comment: Don't forget about the rewrite in config.xml

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is an Ajax solution. There are many extensions available to implement this for you, here are a few examples:

- [VS Ajax- Add To Cart, Add To Wishlist, Add to Compare, Paging, Toolbar](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/vs-ajax-add-to-cart-add-to-wishlist-add-to-compare-paging-toolbar.html),
- [AJAX - Add to Cart, Add to Wishlist](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/add-to-cart-using-ajax-13662.html)

Alternately, if you'd like to implement it yourself, here is a guide:

[Excellence Magento Blog - Ajax Based Add Product to Wishlist and Compare Products](http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/10/27/magento-ajax-based-add-product-to-wishlist-and-compare-products/)

This includes an extensive walkthrough on implementing this feature - as well as the module attached.

Comment: will this extension work for 1.9 vwersion?

Comment: I don't see why not, although neither extension explicitly states that they support 1.9 . Try it on your staging environment and let us know.

Comment: thanks  i will try , did you used any of above extension? any side effects did you faced?

Comment: I have not, no. That's why it's best to always test any extension on a staging environment. Both of the extensions listed though are well reviewed & have a decent user base. Read through the reviews.